# How to update UI at main queue in Swift?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I want to create a splash screen application that I also have a Class named EXClass.
for some reasons the EXClass must initialize in main thread and update some UI. 
please reference following swift code.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    self.windowController = ......
    self.windowController.showWindow(self)

    // In order to show window at the very first time, I create a main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.ex = EXClass()  // this class must init in main thread
    }
}
```

If I init EXClass in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) that init class is ok but update UI is no effect. why?

Comment: What are you doing to update the UI?

Comment: You must write some code, otherwise we cant  help you..

Comment: applicationDidFinishLaunching _does_ run on the main thread.

Comment: @ gnasher729 you are right. but If i don't create a main queue the window can't show at the very first time. the EXClass will does a lot of things.